# Example of non odr-used variable defined in the program

Tags: c++

From the 3.2/4:

> Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline
>   function or variable that it *odr-used*.

I'm interested in example of non-`odr-used` variable.

Comment: @user657267 I'm interested in the following question: Is it true that every variable is odr-used after her definition?

Comment: Please see the definition (C++11 3.2/3), which is cited in the linked question, for the formal language of "odr-used". The purpose of *not* odr-using something is that you don't *need* a definition, but only a declaration. For example, integral constants are often only needed for their value, not for the object itself, so they're often not odr-used.